# GNU-Screen doesn't automatically clear the terminal after detaching

Tags: linux, terminal, putty, gnu-screen

As shown in the following screenshot, after I detaching from a gnu-screen session, the screen isn't cleared, so it's messed up. I have to manually type `clear`.

Here's my environment:

- GNU Screen version 4.04.00 (GNU) 19-Jun-16
- Fedora 24. You can check the untouched /etc/screenrc here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/66bbf9e94f5d5893da7e2a0444986d0a)
- no `~/.screenrc` setting
- terminal is putty remote SSH
- TERM="xterm"

[image: Before detaching screen]

[image: After detaching screen, the text below the cursor remains.]

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21707/clear1-after-detach-in-gnu-screen for answer #1 that works with Cool-Retro-Term under Fedora 29. Mileage may very depending on the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by commenting out two lines in /etc/screenrc

```
# Do not use xterms alternate window buffer.
# This one would not add lines to the scrollback buffer.
#termcap xterm|xterms|xs ti=\E7\E[?47l
#terminfo xterm|xterms|xs ti=\E7\E[?47l
```

Comment: This works, but it leaves me unable to scroll inside the screen session using the mouse wheel or `Shift + Page Up`. This makes this solution unusable for me.

Comment: -1 This is not the proper solution and I am looking for that.

Answer (score 3):

Related to vim-in-screen behavior. I forgot where I found these.

You can solve the problem as typing

`altscreen on`

in ~/.screenrc

Comment: I changed this in cool-retro-term and it doesn't work. It may be CRT but I am not sure.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21707/clear1-after-detach-in-gnu-screen <-- First Answer Works with CRT

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by changing my PuTTY terminal type from `xterm` to `putty` or `putty-256color`.

You can find this setting for your session here: Settings -> Connection > Data > Terminal-type string.

Make sure the machine you're connecting to has the appropriate `putty`/`putty-256color` terminfo file, typically found here: `/usr/share/terminfo/p/`.

Answer (score 0):

This would happen if PuTTY's dialog is set to disable switching between the normal/alternate screens, and at the same time PuTTY uses the old-style xterm controls for switching normal/alternate.  Those controls switched things (and that is disabled), but did the clearing- and save/restore-cursor operations as separate control sequences.  What you see in the misplaced cursor is PuTTY restoring the cursor to the location where was before the application asked PuTTY to switch to the alternate screen.

Some of the history of those control sequences is in the xterm FAQ [Why doesn't the screen clear when running vi?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_tite)

By the way, exiting *from* `screen` is different from exiting from an application running *in* `screen`.  The former depends on an interaction between the terminal settings and `screen`, while the latter depends only upon `screen` (not on the terminal settings).

Comment: I think it's different from the vim-in-screen problem. My vim quits perfectly fine in screen. The console returns back to the state before lunching vim.